# How to pass data with Html Attributes after mapped Array without using another React components?

Tags: html, reactjs, api, attributes, jsx

***I am trying to pass data with HTML attribute without using another component to handleClick but I couldn't handle can anyone help me please***

```
const handleLiClickFirst = (airport) => {
    setFirst(airport.target.innerHTML);
    console.log(airport.target.lat); // I can't read the data here
  };

   <div className="header__first">
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="From"
          variant="outlined"
          value={first}
          onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase())}
        />
        <ul>
          {resultFirst.airports?.map((airport, i) => {
            return (
              <li
                key={airport.iata}
                airport={airport}
                onClick={handleLiClickFirst}
                lat={airport.latitude}
                name={airport.name}
                long={airport.longitude}
              >
                {airport.name}  // I can read the data here
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Random attributes like `airport` and `lat` aren't valid to attach to a native HTML element like `<li>`. However, you should be able to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead to store data on an HTML element.

And you will likely need to use `data-airport={JSON.stringify(airport)}` instead of just passing the JS object. And if you can avoid passing the entire object in, (by saving each of the properties that you need separately, like you are already doing with latitude, for example) that may be best to avoid to prevent creating massive HTML attribute strings.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem without attributes and the handleClick Method after I couldn't reach the data. I removed handleClick from onClick and added the code in onClick

```
        onClick={() => {
              setFirst(airport.name);
              //    setFirstLatlong([airport.latitude,airport.longitude]);
              setFirstLatlong({
                lat: airport.latitude,
                long: airport.longitude,
              });
            }}
```

**@Jacob K** I will try to use your method on an upcoming project. Thank you